# Web data(wiki) scraping python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to obtain lat lng for some university from wikipedia, I have a base url= 'https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_altsprachlicher_Gymnasien' with list of universities and i am from the href getting the the wiki page of  each university to get the lat lng present on their wiki page. I am getting this error an error "NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'" i am unable to rectify this, where am i doing wrong?

```
import time
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_altsprachlicher_Gymnasien')
html = driver.page_source
base_url = 'https://de.wikipedia.org'
url = 'https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_altsprachlicher_Gymnasien'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)

university = []
while True:
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
    links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('.*\/wiki\/.*'))
    for l in links:
        full_link = base_url + l['href']
        town = l['title']
        res = requests.get(full_link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
        info = soup.find('span', attrs={"title":["Breitengrad","Längengrad"]})
        latlong = info.text
        university.append(dict(town_name=town, lat_long=latlong))
        print(university)
```

**Edit 1**
Thanks to @rll i made the edit:

```
if info is not None:
           latlong = info.text
           university.append(dict(town_name=town, postal_code=latlong))
           print(university)
```

Now the code works but I see just the lat but not longitude

sample output : `{'postal_code': '49°\xa072\xa036,73\xa0N', 'town_name': 'Schönborn-Gymnasium Bruchsal'}, {'postal_code': '49°\xa072\xa030,73\xa0N', 'town_name': 'St. Paulusheim'}`
anyways as to how to format this output to get longitude as well , and also format the output sorry i am poor in regex.

**Edit 2**

I worked out to get the the longitude as well with updated code

```
info = soup.find('span', attrs={"title":"Breitengrad"})
info1 = soup.find('span',attrs={"title":"Längengrad"})
        if info is not None:
           latlong = info.text
           longitude = info1.text
           university.append(dict(town_name=town, postal_code=latlong,postal_code1=longitude))
           print(university)
```

Now my output looks like:

```
{'postal_code': '48°\xa045′\xa046,9″\xa0N',
  'postal_code1': '8°\xa014′\xa044,8″\xa0O',
  'town_name': 'Gymnasium Hohenbaden'},
```

So i need help in formatting the lat and long, as i am unable to figure out how to convert for example : `48°\xa045′\xa046,9″\xa0N to 48° 45′ 9″ N`
Thanks

Comment: BeautifulSoup is not finding any span with those titles, so `info` is None. Try doing a find for any span and print them out, my guess is that you will find out why specifically info is None

Comment: I believe they offer an API, that is the recommended method.  Try this link https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Comment: thanks @rll made changes to the code, but still stuck with some issues

Comment: You should really be using WikiData (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2576235) or DbPedia, where all the work has already been done for you!

Comment: thanks for the link @dstudeba, i'll try it out but i haven't tried fetching data through this api so i was using this method, anyways you can help me fix the code that would be helpful.

Comment: Glad you're moving forward at least :) the acknowledgement is nice, but you can also vote a comment up if it helps the post (maybe you were not aware ;) )

Comment: How to decode \xa072\xa030 in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not answering directly, but I always prefer to use MediaWiki's API. And we're lucky to have [`mwclient`](https://github.com/mwclient/mwclient) in Python, which makes working with the API even easier.

So, for what it's worth, here's how I would do it with `mwclient`:

```
import re
import mwclient

site = mwclient.Site('de.wikipedia.org')
start_page = site.Pages['Liste_altsprachlicher_Gymnasien']

results = {}
for link in start_page.links():
    page = site.Pages[link['title']]
    text = page.text()

    try:
        pattern = re.compile(r'Breitengrad.+?([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[\.0-9]+)/N')
        breiten = [float(b) for b in pattern.search(text).group(1).split('/')]

        pattern = re.compile(r'Längengrad.+?([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[\.0-9]+)/E')
        langen = [float(b) for b in pattern.search(text).group(1).split('/')]
    except:
        continue

    results[link['title']] = breiten, langen
```

This gives a tuple of lists `[deg, min, sec]` for each link it succeeds in finding coordinates in:

```
>>> results

{'Akademisches Gymnasium (Wien)': ([48.0, 12.0, 5.0], [16.0, 22.0, 34.0]),
 'Akademisches Gymnasium Salzburg': ([47.0, 47.0, 39.9], [13.0, 2.0, 2.9]),
 'Albertus-Magnus-Gymnasium (Friesoythe)': ([53.0, 1.0, 19.13], [7.0, 51.0, 46.44]),
 'Albertus-Magnus-Gymnasium Regensburg': ([49.0, 1.0, 23.95], [12.0, 4.0, 32.88]),
 'Albertus-Magnus-Gymnasium Viersen-Dülken': ([51.0, 14.0, 46.29], [6.0, 19.0, 42.1]),
 ...
}
```

You could format any way you like:

```
for uni, location in results.items():
    lat, lon = location
    string = """University {} is at {}˚{}'{}"N, {}˚{}'{}"E"""
    print(string.format(uni, *lat+lon))
```

Or convert the DMS coordinates to decimal degrees:

```
def dms_to_dec(coord):
    d, m, s = coord
    return d + m/60 + s/(60*60)

decimal = {uni: (dms_to_dec(b), dms_to_dec(l)) for uni, (b, l) in results.items()}
```

Note, not all of the linked pages might be universities; I didn't check that carefully.

Comment: Thanks for this, never tried api , this is very helpful, i was trying to accomplish using very lengthy way, however can we get this lat and lng from degree format to decimal ?that would be extremely helpful

Comment: Cool, glad it's potentially helpful. I edited my answer, but I'd say you're getting to a point where you probably need to ask another question.

Comment: I am having issues with mwclient, unable to import.. I'll post another question so that you can help .. Thanks