# No module named 'errors' mwclient

Tags: python, pip, mediawiki-api, mwclient

Continuation to this post :[Web data(wiki) scraping python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807203/web-datawiki-scraping-python/33808742#33808742)
@kwinkunks Helped me with the question. However, I am unable to import mwclient.

It throws this error :

```
File "C:\Users\officeMediaIQ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mwclient\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
from errors import *
```

ImportError: No module named 'errors'

Thanks for the help

Comment: How did you install mwclient? Note that you need the development version for Python 3. See the [readme](https://github.com/mwclient/mwclient).